# importing .txt file from Matlab to latex

Tags: pgfplots

I'm trying to plot the modified Bessel functions using latex, so i tried the following
I generated the following .txt file in Matlab

```
z = linspace(0,20);
scale = 1;
Ks = zeros(4,100);
for nu = 0:3
  Ks(nu+1,:) = besselk(nu,z,scale);
end

save('data','Ks','z')
```

and then I tried the following in latex

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}

\pgfplotstableread{
\include{Data}
}\datatable

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot table  {\datatable}
;

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

but I'm not getting an output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're doing a couple of things wrong. First of all, the `save` function in Matlab saves a binary `.mat` file unless you specify otherwise, and `pgpflotstableread` can't read `.mat` files. You need to add the `-ascii` option, or use `dlmwrite`, `fprintf` or some other function that will write data to text files.

Next, you're not supposed to use `\include` inside `pgfplotstableread`, but add the filename directly, i.e. `\pgfplotstableread{filename.txt}` (The extension doesn't have to be `.txt`.) By default `\pgfplotstableread` assumes that columns in the text file are delimited by spaces, if you're using a different column separator you have to specify that, e.g. `\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma]{...}` if commas are used.

Finally, you probably have to choose which columns to plot. When you do `\addplot table {\datatable};`, `pgfplots` will use the first column for the x-values and the second column for the y-values. To plot multiple columns, you need multiple `\addplot`s, e.g.

```
\addplot table[x index=0, y index=1] {\datatable};
\addplot table[x index=0, y index=2] {\datatable};
```

If the columns are named, you can use e.g. `x=NameOfXColumn` instead of `x index=0`.

---

Working example follows. I used Octave via OctaveOnline, but I think the code would be the same in Matlab.

```
z = linspace(0,20);
scale = 1;
Ks = zeros(4,100);
for nu = 0:3
  Ks(nu+1,:) = besselk(nu,z,scale);
end

% Put both variables in one matrix
% transpose them to make the data column oriented - the dimensions of dataOut is 100 x 5
dataOut = [z' Ks'];

% save the new matrix using the `-ascii` option
save('data.dat','dataOut', '-ascii')
```

The LaTeX code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}

% add file name directly, no \input or \include
\pgfplotstableread{data.dat}\datatable

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[ymode=log]
\addplot table {\datatable};
\addplot table[y index=1] {\datatable};
\addplot table[y index=2] {\datatable};
\addplot table[y index=3] {\datatable};
\addplot table[y index=4] {\datatable};

\legend{$\nu=0$, $\nu=1$, $\nu=2$, $\nu=3$}

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1: Great answer!